# Expectation of continuous rv X^2

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I ran the following algorithm to find the expected value of X^2 for a random variable X with pdf:

```
exp(-abs(x)^3/3)
```

This is what I did and my results:

```
reject_env <- function(){
  f <- function(x){exp(-abs(x)^3/3)}
  g <- function(x){1.1*exp(-abs(x)^2/4)}
  reject <- TRUE
  while (reject) {
    x <- rnorm(1)
    y <- runif(1, 0, g(x))
    if (y < f(x)) reject <- FALSE
  }
  return(x)
}


x <- c()
for (i in 1:1000000) {
  x[i] <- reject_env()
}

y = x^2
ybar <- mean(y)
mcse <- sd(y)/sqrt(length(y))
UB <- ybar + mcse*1.96
LB <- ybar - mcse*1.96
cat("The expected value is between [", LB, ",", UB, "]")
```

I end up with: The expected value is between [ 0.6018746 , 0.6048092 ]

This looks correct when you graph f:

```
xgrid <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 100)
plot(xgrid, f(xgrid), type = "l")
```

My question is, how would I just use R's built in numerical integration function to solve this problem?

Comment: The expectation is elementary to evaluate (in the integrals use the substitution $3u=|x|^3,$ integrate from $0$ to $\infty,$ and double that); it equals $3^{2/3} / \Gamma(1/3) \approx 0.776458211378\ldots.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that the function $g = 1.1e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}$ is proportional to the density of a $\mathcal{N}(0,2)$ but in your rejection algorithm you are sampling from a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ instead of a $\mathcal{N}(0,2)$.

If I just replace the $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ by a $\mathcal{N}(0,2)$ in your code I find the interval $[ 0.7751043 , 0.7787279 ]$.

I you want you can use the R function `integrate` to compute approximations of integrals (here approximations on the interval $[-20,20]$).

```
f<-function(x) exp(-abs(x)^3/3)
c=integrate(f=f,-20,20)$value
f2<-function(x) (x*x)*f(x)/c
integrate(f2,-10,10)
```

$c$ is the normalizing constant of $e^{-\frac{\vert x \vert ^3}{3}}$.
The last line gives the message

> 0.7764582 with absolute error < 8.6e-10

which is indeed in the previously computed interval.

Maybe there are better functions to compute integrals in R (like `area` is the `MASS` library).

Comment: In what sense does it matter that the function g is proportional to N(0,2) rather than N(0,1)? g is an envelope function for the creation of an acceptance/rejection region, so isn't it the case that all I care about is that it is >= f at every point x? Except then when I change it to rnorm(1,0,2) I get a different answer from mine and yours... I'm also confused about the constant. Why is the constant the integral of the pdf? We don't know the constant for f(x) = c *pdf. Wouldn't we have to figure that out some other way?

Comment: The purpose is to draw random points under the curve of this envelope function and keep only those which are under the targeted curve. If $X \sim g$ then $(g(X), U)$ where $U \sim \mathcal{U}(0,g(X))$ is uniformly distributed under the curve of $g$. However if you draw $X$ which is not distributed as $g$ then the uniformity doesn't hold anymore. In R the third argument in rnorm(1,0,2) is the standard deviation not the variance, thus you should use rnorm(1,0,sqrt(2)) instead.

Comment: Okay, that all makes perfect sense. Thank you very much.